# How to get the section number of a specific UITableViewCell?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, uikit

How to get the original indexPath.section by the specific UITableViewCell?

```
- (NSString *)sectionForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell {
   //How to get the original indexPath.section by the specific UITableViewCell?
}
```

Answer (score 6):

UITableView has a method which gives you the index path of a particular cell:

```
NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
return path.section;
```

Note that this would return an integer, not a string.

Answer (score 2):

Use the UITableView instance method:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
```